# Google Analytics Streamview with firebase integration

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-analytics

I am looking to integrate google analytics into our back end and connecting the data to make it easier for our team to see everything. I wanted to know if I was able to embed the StreamView map into the website or if there is any other service like this i can add into our backend to see a live user map. Thanks!